# Как сделать из иконки в html кнопку?

Tags: html, css, button, img

```
<div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__icon" src="img/features/brain.jpg" alt="">
```

[image: Нужно, что бы мозг служил кнопкой]

Нужно, что бы мозг служил кнопкой

Comment: В чём у вас проблема? Как вы пытались решить задачу, и что не получилось?

Comment: проблема в следующем: Иконка мозга сейчас служит просто картинкой, а мне нужно, что бы при наводе на неё можно было нажать. Пробовал делать через <button>, но она просто обводит всю область как кнопку. Надеюсь написал понятно

Comment: Стили пытались применить к <button>?

Comment: Прошу просветить. В CSS button подсвечивается красным, то есть не могу редактировать этот элемент. Возможно я делаю это неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Можете различными способами повесить событие click на картинку без кнопки, если вам только кликать по ней надо
2. Можете label использовать.

```
<button hidden id="mybutton"></button>
<label for="mybutton">
    <img class="features__icon" src="img/features/brain.jpg" alt="">
</label>
```

3. К кнопкам можно примениять стили CSS

Comment: Заработало, спасибо